# ice4j connectivity on internet

Tags: nat, ice4j

I downloaded ice4j and was trying Icedistributed example(https://github.com/jitsi/ice4j/blob/master/src/test/java/test/IceDistributed.java) on two machines that are on the internet.
If I run this example on two different machines in my LAN, this example works but somehow its not working on internet.

Below is the log

```
=================== feed the following to the remote agent ===================
v=0
o=ice4j.org 0 0 IN null null
s=-
t=0 0
a=ice-options:trickle
a=ice-ufrag:65v2u1agade6hl
a=ice-pwd:5vlei70a43movu2t77fkhpqfa3
m=audio 49249 RTP/AVP 0
c=IN 125.19.34.60 IP4
a=mid:audio
a=candidate:1 1 udp 2130706431 10.64.16.51 2020 typ host
a=candidate:2 1 udp 2130706431 fe80:0:0:0:50e7:235d:e94a:9977 2020 typ host
a=candidate:4 1 udp 2113937151 fe80:0:0:0:c9d0:ed0d:557e:68af 2020 typ host
a=candidate:6 1 udp 2113937151 fe80:0:0:0:c811:49cc:8301:b637 2020 typ host
a=candidate:3 1 udp 2113932031 192.168.88.1 2020 typ host
a=candidate:5 1 udp 2113932031 192.168.31.1 2020 typ host
a=candidate:7 1 udp 1677724415 125.19.34.60 49249 typ srflx raddr 10.64.16.51 rport 2020
a=candidate:1 2 udp 2130706430 10.64.16.51 2021 typ host
a=candidate:2 2 udp 2130706430 fe80:0:0:0:50e7:235d:e94a:9977 2021 typ host
a=candidate:4 2 udp 2113937150 fe80:0:0:0:c9d0:ed0d:557e:68af 2021 typ host
a=candidate:6 2 udp 2113937150 fe80:0:0:0:c811:49cc:8301:b637 2021 typ host
a=candidate:3 2 udp 2113932030 192.168.88.1 2021 typ host
a=candidate:5 2 udp 2113932030 192.168.31.1 2021 typ host
a=candidate:7 2 udp 1677724414 125.19.34.60 49259 typ srflx raddr 10.64.16.51 rport 2021
a=rtcp:49259
m=video 49261 RTP/AVP 0
c=IN 125.19.34.60 IP4
a=mid:video
a=candidate:1 1 udp 2130706431 10.64.16.51 2022 typ host
a=candidate:2 1 udp 2130706431 fe80:0:0:0:50e7:235d:e94a:9977 2022 typ host
a=candidate:4 1 udp 2113937151 fe80:0:0:0:c9d0:ed0d:557e:68af 2022 typ host
a=candidate:6 1 udp 2113937151 fe80:0:0:0:c811:49cc:8301:b637 2022 typ host
a=candidate:3 1 udp 2113932031 192.168.88.1 2022 typ host
a=candidate:5 1 udp 2113932031 192.168.31.1 2022 typ host
a=candidate:7 1 udp 1677724415 125.19.34.60 49261 typ srflx raddr 10.64.16.51 rport 2022
a=candidate:1 2 udp 2130706430 10.64.16.51 2023 typ host
a=candidate:2 2 udp 2130706430 fe80:0:0:0:50e7:235d:e94a:9977 2023 typ host
a=candidate:4 2 udp 2113937150 fe80:0:0:0:c9d0:ed0d:557e:68af 2023 typ host
a=candidate:6 2 udp 2113937150 fe80:0:0:0:c811:49cc:8301:b637 2023 typ host
a=candidate:3 2 udp 2113932030 192.168.88.1 2023 typ host
a=candidate:5 2 udp 2113932030 192.168.31.1 2023 typ host
a=candidate:7 2 udp 1677724414 125.19.34.60 49267 typ srflx raddr 10.64.16.51 rport 2023
a=rtcp:49267

==============================================================================

Paste remote SDP here. Enter an empty line to proceed:
(we don't mind the [java] prefix in SDP intput)
v=0
o=ice4j.org 0 0 IN null null
s=-
t=0 0
a=ice-options:trickle
a=ice-ufrag:3u54r1agac2sf4
a=ice-pwd:6u1paracg9t86itirv30mk6fvg
m=audio 2020 RTP/AVP 0
c=IN 111.93.62.26 IP4
a=mid:audio
a=candidate:1 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.10.151 2020 typ host
a=candidate:2 1 udp 2130706431 fe80:0:0:0:7521:ed11:4f2b:c6fb 2020 typ host
a=candidate:3 1 udp 1677724415 111.93.62.26 2020 typ srflx raddr 192.168.10.151
rport 2020
a=candidate:1 2 udp 2130706430 192.168.10.151 2021 typ host
a=candidate:2 2 udp 2130706430 fe80:0:0:0:7521:ed11:4f2b:c6fb 2021 typ host
a=candidate:3 2 udp 1677724414 111.93.62.26 2021 typ srflx raddr 192.168.10.151
rport 2021
m=video 2022 RTP/AVP 0
c=IN 111.93.62.26 IP4
a=mid:video
a=candidate:1 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.10.151 2022 typ host
a=candidate:2 1 udp 2130706431 fe80:0:0:0:7521:ed11:4f2b:c6fb 2022 typ host
a=candidate:3 1 udp 1677724415 111.93.62.26 2022 typ srflx raddr 192.168.10.151
rport 2022
a=candidate:1 2 udp 2130706430 192.168.10.151 2023 typ host
a=candidate:2 2 udp 2130706430 fe80:0:0:0:7521:ed11:4f2b:c6fb 2023 typ host
a=candidate:3 2 udp 1677724414 111.93.62.26 2023 typ srflx raddr 192.168.10.151
rport 2023

Apr 14, 2016 6:33:32 PM org.ice4j.ice.Component addRemoteCandidate
INFO: Add remote candidate for audio.RTP: 192.168.10.151:2020/udp/host
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:32 PM org.ice4j.ice.Component addRemoteCandidate
INFO: Add remote candidate for audio.RTP: [fe80:0:0:0:7521:ed11:4f2b:c6fb]:2020/udp/host
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:32 PM org.ice4j.ice.Component addRemoteCandidate
INFO: Add remote candidate for audio.RTP: 111.93.62.26:2020/udp/srflx
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:32 PM org.ice4j.ice.Component addRemoteCandidate
INFO: Add remote candidate for audio.RTCP: 192.168.10.151:2021/udp/host
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:32 PM org.ice4j.ice.Component addRemoteCandidate
INFO: Add remote candidate for audio.RTCP: [fe80:0:0:0:7521:ed11:4f2b:c6fb]:2021/udp/host
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:32 PM org.ice4j.ice.Component addRemoteCandidate
INFO: Add remote candidate for audio.RTCP: 111.93.62.26:2021/udp/srflx
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:35 PM org.ice4j.ice.Component addRemoteCandidate
INFO: Add remote candidate for video.RTP: 192.168.10.151:2022/udp/host
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:35 PM org.ice4j.ice.Component addRemoteCandidate
INFO: Add remote candidate for video.RTP: [fe80:0:0:0:7521:ed11:4f2b:c6fb]:2022/udp/host
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:35 PM org.ice4j.ice.Component addRemoteCandidate
INFO: Add remote candidate for video.RTP: 111.93.62.26:2022/udp/srflx
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:35 PM org.ice4j.ice.Component addRemoteCandidate
INFO: Add remote candidate for video.RTCP: 192.168.10.151:2023/udp/host
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:35 PM org.ice4j.ice.Component addRemoteCandidate
INFO: Add remote candidate for video.RTCP: [fe80:0:0:0:7521:ed11:4f2b:c6fb]:2023/udp/host
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:35 PM org.ice4j.ice.Component addRemoteCandidate
INFO: Add remote candidate for video.RTCP: 111.93.62.26:2023/udp/srflx
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:35 PM org.ice4j.ice.Agent startConnectivityEstablishment
INFO: Start ICE connectivity establishment
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:35 PM org.ice4j.ice.Agent initCheckLists
INFO: Init checklist for stream audio
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:35 PM org.ice4j.ice.Agent initCheckLists
INFO: Init checklist for stream video
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:35 PM org.ice4j.ice.Agent setState
INFO: ICE state changed from Waiting to Running
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:35 PM com.ice4j.test.IceDemoPropertyChangeListener propertyChange
INFO: Agent entered the Running state.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:35 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient startChecks
INFO: Start connectivity checks!
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:36 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: 10.64.16.51:2020/udp/host -> 192.168.10.151:2020/udp/host (audio.RTP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:36 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: [fe80:0:0:0:50e7:235d:e94a:9977]:2020/udp/host -> [fe80:0:0:0:7521:ed11:4f2b:c6fb]:2020/udp/host (audio.RTP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:36 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: [fe80:0:0:0:c9d0:ed0d:557e:68af]:2020/udp/host -> [fe80:0:0:0:7521:ed11:4f2b:c6fb]:2020/udp/host (audio.RTP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:36 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: [fe80:0:0:0:c811:49cc:8301:b637]:2020/udp/host -> [fe80:0:0:0:7521:ed11:4f2b:c6fb]:2020/udp/host (audio.RTP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:36 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: 192.168.88.1:2020/udp/host -> 192.168.10.151:2020/udp/host (audio.RTP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:36 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: 192.168.31.1:2020/udp/host -> 192.168.10.151:2020/udp/host (audio.RTP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:36 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: 10.64.16.51:2020/udp/host -> 111.93.62.26:2020/udp/srflx (audio.RTP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:36 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: 192.168.88.1:2020/udp/host -> 111.93.62.26:2020/udp/srflx (audio.RTP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:36 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: 192.168.31.1:2020/udp/host -> 111.93.62.26:2020/udp/srflx (audio.RTP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:36 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: 10.64.16.51:2021/udp/host -> 192.168.10.151:2021/udp/host (audio.RTCP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:36 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: [fe80:0:0:0:50e7:235d:e94a:9977]:2021/udp/host -> [fe80:0:0:0:7521:ed11:4f2b:c6fb]:2021/udp/host (audio.RTCP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:36 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: [fe80:0:0:0:c9d0:ed0d:557e:68af]:2021/udp/host -> [fe80:0:0:0:7521:ed11:4f2b:c6fb]:2021/udp/host (audio.RTCP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:36 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: [fe80:0:0:0:c811:49cc:8301:b637]:2021/udp/host -> [fe80:0:0:0:7521:ed11:4f2b:c6fb]:2021/udp/host (audio.RTCP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:36 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: 192.168.88.1:2021/udp/host -> 192.168.10.151:2021/udp/host (audio.RTCP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:36 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: 192.168.31.1:2021/udp/host -> 192.168.10.151:2021/udp/host (audio.RTCP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:36 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: 10.64.16.51:2021/udp/host -> 111.93.62.26:2021/udp/srflx (audio.RTCP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:36 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: 192.168.88.1:2021/udp/host -> 111.93.62.26:2021/udp/srflx (audio.RTCP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:36 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: 192.168.31.1:2021/udp/host -> 111.93.62.26:2021/udp/srflx (audio.RTCP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:36 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient updateCheckListAndTimerStates
INFO: CheckList will failed in a few seconds if nosucceeded checks come
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:37 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: 10.64.16.51:2022/udp/host -> 192.168.10.151:2022/udp/host (video.RTP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:37 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: [fe80:0:0:0:50e7:235d:e94a:9977]:2022/udp/host -> [fe80:0:0:0:7521:ed11:4f2b:c6fb]:2022/udp/host (video.RTP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:37 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: [fe80:0:0:0:c9d0:ed0d:557e:68af]:2022/udp/host -> [fe80:0:0:0:7521:ed11:4f2b:c6fb]:2022/udp/host (video.RTP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:37 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: [fe80:0:0:0:c811:49cc:8301:b637]:2022/udp/host -> [fe80:0:0:0:7521:ed11:4f2b:c6fb]:2022/udp/host (video.RTP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:37 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: 192.168.88.1:2022/udp/host -> 192.168.10.151:2022/udp/host (video.RTP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:37 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: 192.168.31.1:2022/udp/host -> 192.168.10.151:2022/udp/host (video.RTP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:37 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: 10.64.16.51:2022/udp/host -> 111.93.62.26:2022/udp/srflx (video.RTP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:37 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: 192.168.88.1:2022/udp/host -> 111.93.62.26:2022/udp/srflx (video.RTP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:37 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: 192.168.31.1:2022/udp/host -> 111.93.62.26:2022/udp/srflx (video.RTP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:37 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: 10.64.16.51:2023/udp/host -> 192.168.10.151:2023/udp/host (video.RTCP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:37 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: [fe80:0:0:0:50e7:235d:e94a:9977]:2023/udp/host -> [fe80:0:0:0:7521:ed11:4f2b:c6fb]:2023/udp/host (video.RTCP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:37 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: [fe80:0:0:0:c9d0:ed0d:557e:68af]:2023/udp/host -> [fe80:0:0:0:7521:ed11:4f2b:c6fb]:2023/udp/host (video.RTCP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:37 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: [fe80:0:0:0:c811:49cc:8301:b637]:2023/udp/host -> [fe80:0:0:0:7521:ed11:4f2b:c6fb]:2023/udp/host (video.RTCP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:38 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: 192.168.88.1:2023/udp/host -> 192.168.10.151:2023/udp/host (video.RTCP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:38 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: 192.168.31.1:2023/udp/host -> 192.168.10.151:2023/udp/host (video.RTCP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:38 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: 10.64.16.51:2023/udp/host -> 111.93.62.26:2023/udp/srflx (video.RTCP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:38 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: 192.168.88.1:2023/udp/host -> 111.93.62.26:2023/udp/srflx (video.RTCP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:38 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient processTimeout
INFO: timeout for pair: 192.168.31.1:2023/udp/host -> 111.93.62.26:2023/udp/srflx (video.RTCP), failing.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:38 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient updateCheckListAndTimerStates
INFO: CheckList will failed in a few seconds if nosucceeded checks come
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:41 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient$1 run
INFO: CheckList for stream audio FAILED
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:43 PM org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient$1 run
INFO: CheckList for stream video FAILED
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:43 PM org.ice4j.ice.Agent checkListStatesUpdated
INFO: ICE state is FAILED
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:43 PM org.ice4j.ice.Agent setState
INFO: ICE state changed from Running to Failed
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:43 PM com.ice4j.test.IceDemoPropertyChangeListener propertyChange
INFO: Agent entered the Failed state.
Apr 14, 2016 6:33:43 PM com.ice4j.test.IceDemoPropertyChangeListener propertyChange
INFO: Total ICE processing time: 491243
```

I am unable to understand the reason because if I see the log, somehow its showing the public ip address and its binding port but somehow connection is not successful with that sdp info. 
Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to proxy hosted on another machine. When I turned turn server on from the code, it works fine. Anyhow all the hosts behind NAT can't work 100% with the stun and this was happening with me also for one of the host behind the NAT of another network on the internet. Enabling the turn works.